React Build Error - Unexpected end of JSON input
I'm completely at a loss. I have a React app I've been working on for some time and yesterday I found I was unable to build it. I keep getting the following error on 'npm run build':
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.
Unexpected end of JSON input
Steps I have taken:

npm cache clean --force
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
rm -rf ~/.npm
npm install
checked all .json formatting
tested the package.json file with node -e
Used yarn to build (same error)

I have created a new React project and was able to build without errors.
I have taken all the packages from package.json in my problem project, pasted them into a new project and was able to build without error.
I'm not sure what to do now other than completely rebuild my project piece by piece.

I am not sure specifically what the problem is but I can tell you the approach I use to find the problem in these kind of situations. If you used git you can make a separate branch and start reverting commit by commit and seeing which commit changed the build from working to non working, it might seem like this will take a while but it will give you a deeper understanding in the end of the framework you are using. Good luck!

I'm having the same issue for my react application since today and i think its a bug in the new NodeJs version. I fixed it by downgrading my version from 23.2.0 (newest at this time) to the LTS 22.11.0. Hope this will do the trick for you aswell.

23.1.0 worked for me as well on 23.1.0-alpine for the docker image

This is one of those cases where ChatGPT and Claude are useless because this is such a recent problem.

I setup my Docker file with node version:22-alpine3.19. Downgrading the NodeJS version works.

As @Max mentioned it's a bug in latest nodejs.
We just changed the first line of the pipeline configuration (bitbucket-pipelines.yml) from image: node to image: node:lts and the problem was solved.
